# How to set Xamarin iOS SDK version for building on Azure Devops

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin, sdk, devops

I have an iOS project targeting SDK version 14.5 on all configurations but when I build it via an Azure Devops pipeline it targets version 13.5. Upon releasing I receive the following message.

> SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 13.2 SDK. All iOS
> apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 14 SDK or
> later, included in Xcode 12 or later.

This tells me it is not reading the value on the project configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this I had to update our hosted build agent OS to use a version of MacOS running XCode 12. At the time of writing this it was MacOS 10.15.

For more info on what software the hosted build agent operating systems come with visit this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#notes-on-choosing-hosted-macos